# Catching Kestrel Startup Errors

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, kestrel-http-server

I'm running a website using Kestrel.  I have an `IWebHost` and I call .Run() on it.

```
var app = host.Build();
app.Run();
```

Usually this works great, but I have a specific situation I'm concerned about.  Sometimes the specified port is in use.  I know I can check to see if a port is in-use during the configuration/setup but, it's always possible that someone will use a port after my check but before Kestrel is listening.  And also, I'm sure there are other issues that could cause the app.Run() line to fail.

When `app.Run()` fails I would like to log an error message to log file.  The problem is that the application seems to crash and I'm unable to handle the exception.

For example, I tried this:

```
    var app = host.Build();

    try
    {
        app.Run();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        throw;
    }
```

But it simply doesn't ever hit `catch` code.

I've searched and found a lot of examples for global exception handling that seem to deal with redirecting the user to an error page, and while I might have simply done it wrong, I haven't been able to get any of those examples to work.

The error message is something similar to this:

> crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
>
> Unable to start Kestrel.

Along with a stacktrace.  I'm able to see this error by running from the command line, but my users will not.  Which is why I really want to be able to catch this/log it.

Can someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is there any demo to reproduce your issue? Fail to reproduce your issue with an invalid port, the `catch (Exception e)` will be hit.

Comment: @TaoZhou - Thank you for your comment.  You are right, I'm not able to reproduce this with a demo, there must be something I've done wrong in my code.  I'll continue to see if I can figure it out/provide a sample

Comment: Thank you everyone.  @johnluke.laue 's answer does seem to do the trick.  The difficulty I was experiencing was eventually tracked back to a listener that was explicitly calling Environment.Exit(0) before the exception could propagate up to my handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `.CaptureStartupErrors(false)`. Documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-2.2#capture-startup-errors).

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();       
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Fatal(ex, "App crashed");
        }
        finally
        {
            Log.CloseAndFlush();
        }            
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .CaptureStartupErrors(false) //allow startup errors to propagate
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

Comment: Run will lock until shutdown, the task from RunAsync won't end until shutdown aswell.
Is there any way to track the startup errors but still have a Task as reference for shutdown? Is just can come up having some timeout after i call webTask = IWebHost.RunAsnyc(); Task.Delay(1000); if(webTask.isFaulted) throw webTask.Exception; else Return webTask